# Search address in Apple map

Tags: ios

I want to open apple map by tapping on address. If user clicks on address field it should be redirected to apple maps. Address field is string. There is no latitude or longitude. I don't want current location to be searched.

Comment: what do know about mapkit: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this:

```
NSString * address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?q= FG, Block - 1"]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

It will navigate to apple map with given address.

Comment: i want to use map kit..map app of the iPhone not url

Comment: do you want to use mapKit framework in your iOS Application ?

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial